# How to open a file in the same VSCode instance using terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code Version: 1.87.2
OS Version: Windows 10 22H2 19045.4046

I'm having a weird issue trying to open my files from terminal in VSCode on windows. As far as I know using -r should force opening a file in the same instance of VSCode, but no matter how my settings is setup I still get a new instance opening up every time!

Already googled solutions and searched through stackoverflow, tried both `"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off"`
`"window.openWithoutArgumentsInNewWindow": "off"`
Doesn't seem to have any effects on my issue. Am I missing something?

note: working on a Django project repo if it helps.

Steps to Reproduce:

- Open a new terminal (PowerShell) in your workspace.
- `cd` to your desired directory
- Run `code -r yourfile.py`
- A new instance of VSCode will pop up opening yourfile.py instead of yourfile.py opening in the same VSCode instance

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

- Edit 1: Think it could potentially be a bug of some sorts, either at my end or globally. Made a [ticket on VSCode github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/207594) to see. will update if I get more info or guidance on this.
- Edit 2: For some weird reason, if I run the executable from the command line, it would grab `code -r filename.ext` just fine. But if I open the executable using windows explorer it somehow gives me some sort of local instance that terminal doesn't grab, even though both executables are running under the same username and privileges. Can't figure out why and how, but at least I've got a decent workaround for the moment thanks to
  [Tripp Kinetics](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3605497/tripp-kinetics) comments :)

Comment: Is the behavior the same whether you're using Terminal or just a Command-Prompt console window?

Comment: @TrippKinetics Haven't checked it before, just tried and the result is the same. However just found out right after it opens a new instance, if I try to open any other files it actually uses the newly opened VSCode instance! but the main one where I'm at my workspace doesn't grab the file!

Comment: That is truly bizarre.  It implies that there's a "default VS Code window" link that is local to the command-line session.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Yeah! But thanks for mentioning the cmd try, it made me realize I could do it once and setup the second one to be my workspace as a workaround for now! Cheers mate!

Comment: Hmm.  When you look at your existing VS Code window in the Task Manager window, is it listed as running with the correct userid?  As in, the same userid as the Terminal window is running under?

Comment: @TrippKinetics Yes, they're both running under the same logged in user. Double checked the Code.exe path to see if it's run as admin or something, but nope.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Found the weird trick! If I open the first instance using cmd or powershell it works just fine. apparently running VSCode by windows explorer gives me another type of instance! lol
I really appreciate the direction you led me on this, saved me lots of headaches. Can you simply provide an answer as "run the first instance using the terminal" so I can mark it as the correct answer to this?

Comment: You got it, boss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start the initial VS Code window using the Terminal window, then subsequent calls to the `code.exe` executable from the same window will open the new file in the same window.  So, just make sure to start your session from the Windows Terminal instead of from Windows Explorer, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Appreciate the correct answer, made my day easier ^_^

Answer (score -1):

I do not understand exactly what you want to do.
Here are some of my suggestions:

Running python code in the vsc terminal?

> python your_file.py

Running a pip command?

> python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

The terminal does not have a -r flag. This is also true for Python.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However the problem is not with Python, This is specifically a VSCode issue. 
Let's say you have a workspace open in visual studio code, and you're using the terminal to do your stuff. You'd normally open a new file using the command "code filename.ext". Now the problem is you'd want to open the file within your VSCode instance, but you get a new VSCode instance open with that file outside of your current workspace.

Comment: Docs suggest using "-r" argument for "code" command would enforce file to open in the same VSCode instance, like say "code -r filename.ext", but no matter the approach I'm getting a new instance of VSCode opening every time.